# Streaming data with AWS Lambda to React client

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, streaming, aws-amplify

I have an event that whenever it happens I want to send a packet of data to my client. I have tried to use AWS's `streamifyResponse` package, as follows:
First, I tried this:

```
responseStream.setContentType('application/json')

// whenever the event happens, get some data (in the variable json) and the perform
responseStream.write(json)

// and then wrap the entire function
export const function = streamifyResponse(helper)
```

I have also tried with pipelining:

```
// define the pipeline:
const pipeline = require("util").promisify(require("stream").pipeline)

// whenever the event happens:
const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(json))
await pipeline(requestStream, zlib.createGzip(), responseStream)
```

However this gives me the console error `MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 unpipe listeners added to [ResponseStream]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`.

On the frontend, I have tried both Amplify's `API.post` method and the normal `fetch` method. In the fetch case, I tried to use a reader to extract the streamed data:

```
const reader = response.body!.getReader()
console.log("reader", reader)
while (true) {
  const { done, value } = await reader.read();
  if (done) {
    // Do something with last chunk of data then exit reader
      console.log("done streaming")
      return
  }
  console.log("streamed value", value)
}
```

The Amplify API has been the only one that has triggered the successful stream on the backend, yet I am still unable to get the data continuously instead of all at the end. Finally, I added this in my api listing:

```
url: {
    streaming: true
}
```

My questions are these: Am I correctly setting up the stream on the backend? If so, what is the best way to read it as it is realeased on the frontend?

Thank you!

Comment: "I have an event that whenever it happens I want to send a packet of data to my client". What exactly does it mean? Streaming Lambdas return a chunked response within a single invocation. You use streaming when you need to send multiple packets of data for a single "event" (meaning a single invocation of a Lambda). Can you please elaborate a little bit more on your use case?

Comment: `11 unpipe listeners added to [ResponseStream]`: this is normal, if you have 11 pipelines running in parallel, but nothing in the code you've posted indicates you're doing this. Can you please post a minimally reproducible example of your problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To stream with AWS Lambda from the BE you should have

Stream Creation: Utilizes the streamifyResponse package to create a stream from the AWS Lambda response.

Data Handling: Data is sent to this stream whenever a specific event occurs.
Stream Conversion: The Readable.from() function creates a readable stream from the data.

Gzip Transformation: This stream is piped through a gzip transform stream and then to the response stream.

```
// Backend
const streamifyResponse = require('aws-serverless-express/streamifyResponse')
const zlib = require('zlib')
const { Readable } = require('stream')
const { pipeline } = require('util')

const helper = (req, res) => {
  const responseStream = streamifyResponse.createResponseStream(res)
  responseStream.setContentType('application/json')

  // whenever the event happens:
  const json = JSON.stringify({ data: 'your data' })
  const requestStream = Readable.from(Buffer.from(json))
  pipeline(requestStream, zlib.createGzip(), responseStream, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error('Pipeline failed', err)
    } else {
      console.log('Pipeline succeeded')
    }
  })
}

exports.handler = streamifyResponse(helper)
```

Notice that the pipeline function from Node.js is used to handle backpressure and errors effectively.

And to fetch from the FE

Stream Consumption: The frontend uses the Fetch API to request and continuously read the streamed data.

Reader Implementation: A reader (from response.body.getReader()) is used to extract streamed data as it is released.

Continuous Data Flow: The goal is to enable continuous data flow rather than receiving all data at the end.

```
// Frontend
fetch('your-api-url', { method: 'POST' })
  .then(response => {
    const reader = response.body.getReader()
    return new ReadableStream({
      start(controller) {
        function push() {
          reader.read().then(({ done, value }) => {
            if (done) {
              controller.close()
              return
            }
            controller.enqueue(value)
            push()
          })
        }
        push()
      }
    })
  })
  .then(stream => {
    return new Response(stream, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }).json()
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log(result)
  })
```

And at this point, the Amplify API method has been successful in triggering the backend stream, though continuous data reading is still a challenge.

Best of luck!